# What is the human performance on ImageNet, the top 1 error? (not top 5 error)

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

What is the human performance on ImageNet, the top 1 error? (not top 5 error).
The best of the machine learning algorithm top 1 error is 11.6% ,according to thie [website](https://paperswithcode.com/sota/image-classification-on-imagenet) https://paperswithcode.com/sota/image-classification-on-imagenet

.

Answer (score 1):

The ImageNet top-1 error rate for humans is unknown.  [Russakovsky et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0575) and [Andrej Karpathy](http://karpathy.github.io/2014/09/02/what-i-learned-from-competing-against-a-convnet-on-imagenet/) only discussed the ImageNet top-5 error rate for humans.

Comment: As a side note: In the paper following your first link they state "However, in practice we found that all three measures of error (top-5, top-1, and hierarchical) produced the same ordering of results. Thus, since ILSVRC2012 we have been exclusively using the top-5 metric which is the simplest and most suitable to the dataset.". That might be the reason why the sources for the human top-5-error rates (which are from after 2012) do not make any statements with regards to top-1 error.